# Alias git stash poop to pop?

Tags: git, command-line, command-line-interface

This is an admittedly silly question, but I honestly don't know if this is possible.

I often mistype "git stash pop" (never-mind why).  Can I map/shortcut/alias my typo to what it's supposed to be?

Comment: I misspelled this today, I was wondering what I would find if i googled `git stash poop`

Comment: and then you find this: https://github.com/markhobson/git-stash-poop

Comment: 9 years later and this is my greatest contribution to Stack Overflow. I'm so proud!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
git config --global alias.sp 'stash pop'
```

then `git sp` expands to `git stash pop`

Answer (score 17):

Define a shell function:

```
git() {
  if [ "$1" == "stash" -a "$2" == "poop" ]; then
    shift; shift; command git stash pop "$@"
  else
    command git "$@"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Technically this is the correct answer, but I think using an alias to avoid the problem all together was a better overall solution.

Answer (score 16):

For those that need the properly generated output...

```
if [ "$1" == "stash" -a "$2" == "poop" ]
  then
      command git stash pop
      echo "
   )  )
  (   ) (
   ) _   )
    ( \_
  _(_\ \)__
 (____\___))"
  else
      command git "$@"
  fi;
}
```